# Response Content-Type differs from my @Produces annotation. Why? Does it matter?

Tags: http, jax-rs, resteasy

Our API is undergoing a versioning exercise.  I thought it would be a simple matter of specifying the version value in my code's @Produces like

```
/**
 * PUT Bind.
 */
@RolesAllowed( "device" )
@PUT
@Consumes( "application/vnd.bob.app.bind+json; v=2" )
@Produces( "application/vnd.bob.app.bind-resp+json; v=2" )
@Path( "{platform: x|x1|yyz}/devices/bind" )
public Response putBind_v2( @PathParam( "platform" ) String platform, String manifest );
```

But I observe on my responses in the browser what I get back on Content-Type has wrapped the value of v= in quotes even though my request's Accept header specified v=2 without the quotes.

```
Accept: application/vnd.bob.app.bind+json;v=2
....
Content-Type: application/vnd.bob.app.bind-resp+json;v="2";charset=UTF-8
```

Where did the extra quotes come from, how do I stop them, or does it not actually matter?  I mean do v=2 and v="2" mean exactly the same thing somewhere in the realm of HTTP RFC Spec-iness?

My application is leveraging the RESTEasy framework.

Comment: Uh oh.  Nothing but 10 views in 6 hours and no answers.  It seems that v=1 and v="1" are synonyms as the RFC (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) speaks of the parameter like "... ";" token [ "=" ( token | quoted-string ) ]..." as if token and quoted-string are equivalent.  I don't see, though, where it states that they are equivalent.  Freaking specs.